# Streaming mp4 in Chrome with rails, nginx and send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, google-chrome, nginx, html5-video

I can't for the life of me stream a mp4 to Chrome with a html5 `<video>` tag.  If I drop the file in `public` then everything is gravy and works as expected.  But if I try to serve it using `send_file`, pretty much everything imaginable goes wrong.  I am using a rails app that is proxied by nginx, with a `Video` model that has a `location` attribute that is an absolute path on disk.

At first I tried:

```
def show
  send_file Video.find(params[:id]).location
end
```

And I was sure I would be basking in the glory that is modern web development.  Ha.  This plays in both Chrome and Firefox, but neither seek and neither have any idea how long the video is.  I poked at the response headers and realized that `Content-Type` is being sent as `application/octet-stream` and there is no `Content-Length` set.  Umm... wth?

Okay, I guess I can set those in rails:

```
def show
  video = Video.find(params[:id])
  response.headers['Content-Length'] = File.stat(video.location).size
  send_file(video.location, type: 'video/mp4')
end
```

At this point everything works pretty much as expected in Firefox.  It knows how long the video is and seeking works as expected.  Chrome appears to know how long the video is (doesn't show timestamps, but seek bar looks appropriate) but seeking doesn't work.

Apparently Chrome is pickier than Firefox.  It requires that the server respond with a `Accept-Ranges` header with value `bytes` and respond to subsequent requests (that happen when the users seeks) with `206` and the appropriate portion of the file.

Okay, so I borrowed some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604330/4283486) and then I had this:

```
video = Video.find(params[:id])

file_begin = 0
file_size = File.stat(video.location).size
file_end = file_size - 1

if !request.headers["Range"]
  status_code = :ok
else
  status_code = :partial_content
  match = request.headers['Range'].match(/bytes=(\d+)-(\d*)/)
  if match
    file_begin = match[1]
    file_end = match[2] if match[2] && !match[2].empty?
  end
  response.header["Content-Range"] = "bytes " + file_begin.to_s + "-" + file_end.to_s + "/" + file_size.to_s
end
response.header["Content-Length"] = (file_end.to_i - file_begin.to_i + 1).to_s
response.header["Accept-Ranges"]=  "bytes"
response.header["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "binary"
send_file(video.location,
:filename => File.basename(video.location),
:type => 'video/mp4',
:disposition => "inline",
:status => status_code,
:stream =>  'true',
:buffer_size  =>  4096)
```

Now Chrome attempts to seek, but when you do the video stops playing and never works again until the page reloads.  Argh.  So I decided to play around with curl to see what was happening and I discovered this:

> $ curl --header "Range: bytes=200-400" http://localhost:8080/videos/1/001.mp4
>    ftypisomisomiso2avc1mp41       �moovlmvhd��@��trak\tkh��
>
> $ curl --header "Range: bytes=1200-1400" http://localhost:8080/videos/1/001.mp4
>    ftypisomisomiso2avc1mp41       �moovlmvhd��@��trak\tkh��

No matter the byte range request, the data always starts from the beginning of the file.  The appropriate amount of bytes is returned (201 bytes in this case), but it's always from the beginning of the file.  Apparently nginx respects the `Content-Length` header but ignores the `Content-Range` header.

My `nginx.conf` is untouched default:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

and my app.conf is pretty basic:

```
upstream unicorn {
server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80 default deferred;
root /vagrant/public;
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
client_max_body_size 4G;
keepalive_timeout 5;
}
```

First I tried the nginx 1.4.x that comes with Ubuntu 14.04, then tried 1.7.x from a ppa - same results.  I even tried apache2 and had exactly the same results.

I would like to reiterate that the video file is *not* the problem.  If I drop it in `public` then nginx serves it with the appropriate mime types, headers and everything needed for Chrome to work properly.

So my question is a two-parter:

- Why doesn't nginx/apache handle all this stuff automagically with `send_file` (`X-Accel-Redirect`/`X-Sendfile`) like it does when the file is served statically from `public`?  Handling this stuff in rails is so backwards.
- How the heck can I actually use send_file with nginx (or apache) so that Chrome will be happy and allow seeking?

---

> Update 1

Okay, so I thought I'd try to take the complication of rails out of the picture and just see if I could get nginx to proxy the file correctly.  So I spun up a dead-simple nodjs server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {
    'X-Accel-Redirect': '/path/to/file.mp4'
});
res.end();
}).listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

And chrome is happy as a clam. =/  `curl -I` even shows that `Accept-Ranges: bytes` and `Content-Type: video/mp4` is being inserted by nginx automagically - as it *should* be.  What could rails be doing that's preventing nginx from doing this?

---

> Update 2

I might be getting closer...

If I have:

```
def show
  video = Video.find(params[:id])
  send_file video.location
end
```

Then I get:

```
$ curl -I localhost:8080/videos/1/001.mp4
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.7.9
Date: Sun, 18 Jan 2015 12:06:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="001.mp4"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Cache-Control: private
Set-Cookie: request_method=HEAD; path=/
X-Meta-Request-Version: 0.3.4
X-Request-Id: cd80b6e8-2eaa-4575-8241-d86067527094
X-Runtime: 0.041953
```

And I have all the problems described above.

But if I have:

```
def show
  video = Video.find(params[:id])
  response.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = video.location
  head :ok
end
```

Then I get:

```
$ curl -I localhost:8080/videos/1/001.mp4
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.7.9
Date: Sun, 18 Jan 2015 12:06:02 GMT                                                                                                                                                                            
Content-Type: text/html                                                                                                                                                                                        
Content-Length: 186884698                                                                                                                                                                                      
Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Jan 2015 03:49:30 GMT                                                                                                                                                                   
Connection: keep-alive                                                                                                                                                                                         
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: request_method=HEAD; path=/
ETag: "54bb2d4a-b23a25a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

And everything works perfectly.

But why?  Those should do exactly the same thing.  And why doesn't nginx set `Content-Type` automagically here like it does for the simple nodejs example?  I have `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'` set. I have moved it back and forth between `application.rb` and `development.rb` with the same results.  I guess I never mentioned... this is rails 4.2.0.

---

> Update 3

Now I've changed my unicorn server to listen on port 3000 (since I already changed nginx to listen on 3000 for the nodejs example).  Now I can make requests directly to unicorn (since it's listening on a port and not a socket) so I have found that `curl -I` directly to unicorn shows that no `X-Accel-Redirect` header is sent and just `curl`ing unicorn directly actually sends the file.  It's like `send_file` isn't doing what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *finally* have the answers to my original questions.  I didn't think I'd ever get here.  All my research had lead to dead-ends, hacky non-solutions and "it just works out of the box" (well, not for me).

> Why doesn't nginx/apache handle all this stuff automagically with send_file (X-Accel-Redirect/X-Sendfile) like it does when the file is served statically from public? Handling this stuff in rails is so backwards.

They do, but they have to be configured properly to please Rack::Sendfile (see below).  Trying to handle this in rails is a hacky non-solution.

> How the heck can I actually use send_file with nginx (or apache) so that Chrome will be happy and allow seeking?

I got desperate enough to start poking around rack source code and that's where I found my answer, in the comments of `Rack::Sendfile`.  They are structured as documentation that you can find at [rubydoc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Sendfile).

For whatever reason, `Rack::Sendfile` requires the front end proxy to send a `X-Sendfile-Type` header.  In the case of nginx it also requires a `X-Accel-Mapping` header.  The documentation also has examples for apache and lighttpd as well.

One would think the rails documentation could link to the Rack::Sendfile documentation since send_file does not work out of the box without additional configuration.  Perhaps I'll submit a pull request.

In the end I only needed to add a couple lines to my app.conf:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  root /vagrant/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect; # ADDITION
    proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /=/; # ADDITION
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
}
```

Now my original code works as expected:

```
def show
  send_file(Video.find(params[:id]).location)
end
```

Edit:

Although this worked initially, it stopped working after I restarted my vagrant box and I had to make further changes:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.app.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  root /vagrant/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location ~ /files(.*) { # NEW
    internal;             # NEW
    alias $1;             # NEW
  }                       # NEW

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
    proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /=/files/; # CHANGED
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 5;
}
```

I find this whole thing of mapping one URI to another and then mapping that URI to a location on disk to be totally unnecessary.  It's useless for my use case and I'm just mapping one to another and back again.  Apache and lighttpd don't require it.  But at least it works.

I also added `Mime::Type.register('video/mp4', :mp4)` to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` so the file is served with the correct mime type.

Comment: should `location ~ /files(.*)` be `location ~ /files/(.*)`