# Rails + thin: Not possible to download large files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

I have a rails app where users can manage large files (currently up to 15 GB). They have also the possibility to download the stored files.

Everything works perfect for files < 510 MB. But for > 510 MB, the download stops after 522,256 KB (510 MB).

I think `thin` produces this issue. When I start my dev server using thin, I cannot download the complete file. When I start the dev server using webrick, everything works.

I used `top` to compare the RAM/CPU behavior, but both server, thin and webrick, behave the same way. In development, both server read the complete file into RAM and then send it to the user/client.

I tried to change some options of `send_file` like `stream`, or `buffer_size`. I also set `length` manually. But again, I was not able to download the complete file using thin.

I can reproduce this behavior using Firefox, Chrome, and curl.

The problem is that my productive rails app uses 4 thin servers behind an nginx proxy. Currently, I cannot use unicorn, or passenger.

In development, I use `thin 1.6.3`, `rails 4.1.8`, `ruby 2.1.2`.

```
def download
  file_path = '/tmp/big_file.tar.gz' # 5 GB
  send_file(file_path, buffer_size: 4096, stream: true)
end
```

Comment: What have you observed happening?  I didn't see support for 'stream' in the send_file API: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file But there was some support for X-SendFile, which might be the more appropriate choice.  Thin supports Rack, which in turn provides the X-SendFile translation for the web server.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Ups, `stream` is something old. I also tried `x_sendfile` without effect. The download stops and Chrome, or Firefox 'thinks' the file was successfully downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `send_file`, it is ideal to use a front end proxy to pass off the responsibility of serving the file.  You said you are using nginx in production, so:

In your `production.rb` file, uncomment `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'`.

You will also have to change your nginx configuration to accommodate `Rack::Sendfile`.  Its documentation is located [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Sendfile).  The changes amount to adding:

```
proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /=/files/; # or something similar that doesn't interfere with your routes
```

to your existing location block and adding an additional `location` block that handles the `X-Accel-Mapping` that you added.  That new location block might look like:

```
location ~ /files(.*) {
  internal;             
  alias $1;             
}
```

You will know it is working correctly when you ssh to your production server and `curl -I` the thin server (**not** nginx) and see a `X-Accel-Redirect` header.  `curl` (no `-I`) directly to the `thin` server should *not* send the file contents.

You can see my recent struggle with nginx and send_file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008564/streaming-mp4-in-chrome-with-rails-nginx-and-send-file).