# nginx + unicorn + rails + streaming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, audio-streaming, x-accel-redirect

I am trying to stream audio using using nginx, unicorn, and rails 4. 
I am using following these two links : 
[one](https://blog.echoplex.us/2014/08/20/so-you-want-to-stream-videoaudio-with-rails/) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008564/streaming-mp4-in-chrome-with-rails-nginx-and-send-file) 
and this is what I have got so far -->

nginx.conf

```
 location /protected/ {
            internal;
            alias /$1/;     #should end up evaluating the same thing
    }

    location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
            proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping ^/*=/protected/$1;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:<port>/;
    }
```

I send file from my controller as :

```
send_file(/home/full/path/file.mp3, 
            :filename => "filename.mp3",
            :type => "audio/mpeg",
            :disposition => "inline",
            :stream => 'true',
            :buffer_size  => 4096)
```

Now, using unicorn and nginx I am able to listen to the song, but not seek. This was happening with out nginx as well. I want to be able to seek. This I found that putting these two lines in production.rb will solve the issue :

So now, in my production.rb I have :

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # specifically for nginx
config.middleware.insert 0, Rack::Sendfile, config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header # make sure it loads before any other middleware
```

But now I get 403 Forbidden error. Any help anyone ?

Comment: update : tried changing it to "alias /$1;" (removed front slash)... still 403 forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution ..
So basically Nginx works within the directory, so if yo cant `cd` to that directory with the nginx user, then you will get a 403 forbidden error. You can confirm by using `stat`.

```
sudo -u www-data stat /path
```

It will fail if nginx user cant get to that path. 
Then, you can use `gpasswd` command to add user to a group and solve the issue.